# calling an api service from flask with a callback response

Tags: python, ajax, flask

How do I capture a response from calling an API that is making that response to a specific callbackurl for the client to see?

Suppose I am making an ajax post to some backend url in flask:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'api-req',
   data: {'d1': '{{ d1 }}', 'd2': d2},
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //should do something else here
   }
});
```

So far so good, the url is making a requests post to some API service:

```
@public.route('/api-req', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def api_req():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        d1 = request.form['d1']
        d2 = request.form['d2']

        api_url = f'{base_url}/api'
        api_data = {"d1": d1, "d2": d2, "callbackUrl": "http://www.myurl.com/api-service/response"}

        r = requests.post(sign_url, json=sign_data)

    return r.text # should return something else

@public.route('/api-service/response', methods=['POST'])
    def api_resp():
        # do something here to capture and send to client which is waiting 
        pass
```

But now I cannot figure out how to capture the response from the API service and send that to the client frontend to move on.

Answer (score 0):

You need some ‘mediator’ to exchange data between your endpoint and the callback url handler which supports waiting for data readiness, e.g. using RabbitMQ you can ‘subscribe’ to a message with some id and then wait unless callback puts  that message into a queue

Comment: isnt’t a massage queue a bit overkill for something like this?

Comment: To my opinion not more than handling user request through a chain of 3 http requests

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if i understand, but I think you can hookup your client with a websocket which will receive notifications for when a specific call is finished, the response API will then publish to it

Answer (score 0):

https://language-tools.ec.europa.eu/assets/pages/05_example_python.html

Check this solution from the EU with a callback asynchronous response from the server.
It involves an intermediary route:

```
@app.route('/checkResult', methods=['POST'])
```

...
https://language-tools.ec.europa.eu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34934219)